# Remove (a), (b) from subfigure numbering, but keep the subfigure caption?

Tags: subfloats

I've a question on the labels in the subfigure environment. I would like to remove the (a) and (b) and insert something else instead. This 'new' caption is different for every subfigure and not a logical counter (so not i, ii or so). 
Can any body help me?

I've added a figure showing the current situation (top) and how I would like it to be (bottom).

[image: The top row in the figure is how I have got it now, the bottom row is how I would like it to be!]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just stack the subcaption text under the subfigure.  You can change the fontsize of the subcaptions just by changing the `\footnotesize` to the desired size.  The gap between figure and caption is controlled by the optional argument to `\stackunder` and is, in this example, set to `5pt` (the default is 3pt).

Note that the subcaptions in this technique, will not automatically word-wrap.  In your case, there was no need for wrapping, since they were short labels.  If wrapping were needed, the last argument to `\stackunder` could be a `\parbox`.

I further assumed, that since you wished to remove the `(a)`, `(b)`, that you had no desire to separately reference the individual subfigures.  You can still reference the overall figure with `\ref{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\footnotesize
\stackunder[5pt]{\includegraphics[width=2in,height=.7in]{fileA}}{MRI-CGCM3}%
\hspace{1cm}%
\stackunder[5pt]{\includegraphics[width=2in,height=.7in]{fileB}}{NorESM1-M}
\caption{November to April}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 131):

You can use

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
```

locally:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Test subfigure 1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{Test subfigure 2}
\end{subfigure}%
\caption{Two subfigures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to use `\caption*` instead of `\caption`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption*{Test subfigure 1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-b}
\caption*{Test subfigure 2}
\end{subfigure}%
\caption{Two subfigures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This should be the best answer !

Comment: However: using `\caption*`, labels cannot be used anymore on the subfigures.

Comment: This is really useful!!!

Comment: @Derlin True. But, not giving label (a), (b), .. for subfigures of Figure 1 and later calling them Figure 1a, Figure 1b etc. is odd.

Answer (score 20):

Like `subcaption`,  the `subfig` package also have the same option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}
\begin{document}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[Test subfigure 1]{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\hfill
\subfloat[Test subfigure 2]{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
\caption{Two subfigures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But if you do not need the numeration of the subfloats captions ... there are some reason to still use `subcaption` or `subfig` ?

For example, the same result can be obtained simply with 2 columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\
Test subfigure 1
\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}\\
Test subfigure 2
\end{multicols}
\caption{Two subfigures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using subfloat[]{\includegraphics[]{}} command. Just remove '[]'.

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[]{figure1}}
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[]{figure2}}
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[]{figure3}}
    \caption{captions}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: What I spent time looking for. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a case where I needed only one such label remove.
When declaring the subfigure you can add `\empty` which will remove the letter for that specific subfigure

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,multicol}
\begin{document}
   \begin{figure}
       \begin{multicols}{2}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[\empty]{example-image-a}
            \includegraphics[\empty]{example-image-b}
        \end{multicols}
    \caption{Two subfigures}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Where can OP write text below subfigures?