# Adding an image of a colorbar to look like it is a common colorbar to two or more subfigures

Tags: subfloats

[Edited]:
I am not using any plot functions such as `pgfplots` to create plots. I am importing saved images to be displayed in the document. I am adding a figure that has 4 subfigures. These plots are from COMSOL software and each of them have their own colorbar. This makes the captions such as (a), (b) and so on to appear not centred with respect to each of the subfigures. Since the colorbar of all the plots are the same, I intend to have the subfigures in two-by-two configuration and have a big common colorbar image on the right starting from the top and extends till bottom.

So I played around with the minipage and subfigure commands and I have almost got what I need. The updated code is below:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{fig1a_new}}
\addtocounter{subfigure}{1}
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{fig1c_new}}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.1mm}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\addtocounter{subfigure}{-2}
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{fig1b_new}}
\addtocounter{subfigure}{1}
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{fig1d_new}}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.1mm}
\begin{minipage}{0.01\textwidth}
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[height = 7.8cm,width=1.2cm]{colorbar}}
\end{minipage}
```

giving me an output that looks like this:
[image: Output]

The minipage does not start exactly from the beginning of text column and extends outside the text column on the right. Using `flushleft` didn't help. I think the help for removing the numbering from subfigures in another post will help to remove number from under the colorbar. Can you please advise me on how to align the minipages so that all the elements of the figure fit into the desired column?

Comment: I had a similar problem recently. Have a look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297512/common-colorbar-over-groupplot . The solution uses external figures and a colorbar from `pgfplots`

Comment: Thank you krtek. Please read the update that I just added. Do you think adding rest of the figures using minipage and using pgfplots just for the colorbar will work?

Comment: I guess you could add something like `\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}` to your last subfigure to avoid the number. I currently have no possibility to try that here. And sure, It should be possible to add the colorbar from my earlier link inside the last minipage.

Comment: See this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165513/44634 for a local version of labelformat

Comment: Please make your code compilable. Don't leave people to have to try to figure out the rest in order to see if they even understand the problem and might be able to help. You can use e.g. `example-image-a` instead of your own graphics to make a document which people can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the problem and experiment with solutions.